# using a third variable as a fill aesthethic in geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient, fill, continuous

I am trying to add an extra dimension to my histogram by using a continuous variable to fill the bars. The following syntax however, gives me grey bars:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, fill = hp)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), binwidth = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(label = function(x) paste0(round(x *100), "%")) +
  labs(x = "miles per gallon",
       y = "percentage of cars",
       fill = "horsepower") +
  theme(legend.position = c(.8, .8)) +
  scale_fill_continuous()
```

[image]

using a discrete scale with a factor transformed variable works:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, fill = factor(hp))) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), binwidth = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(label = function(x) paste0(round(x *100), "%")) +
  labs(x = "miles per gallon",
       y = "percentage of cars",
       fill = "horsepower") +
  theme(legend.position = c(.8, .8)) +
  scale_fill_discrete()
```

[image]

We can clearly see that this adds information. Namely that HP seems to be inversely related to MPG.

This is exactly what I would want to achieve.

Can anybody explain this behavior and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on the question, but the plot looks the way it does because you are looking at HP as a factor when it is actually a numeric variable.

Usually a histogram is used to show information about a single variable rather than two. In this case, you are interested in the relationship between two variables so another plot might be more appropriate. Is there a reason you did not want to use a scatterplot to show this relationship? Scatterplots are usually better for comparing two numeric variables.

I think this shows the same thing (i.e., HP and MPG are inversely related) a little more clearly.

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]